# Simulator wont start on home TableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, debugging, storyboard

I've created a table view which is embeded in a Navigation Controller as such and connects to another view controller.  I've the connection from the table to the navigation controller as a modal segue and the segue from the table bar to the View Controller as a push segue yet I am still getting the error:

> Unsupported Configuration
>       Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier 
>       for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:

This worked last week and now its not.  Ive tried adding storyboard IDs but thats not working.  I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check your start point in your storyboard? In other words, on the left side of your starting navigation controller, do you have the arrow pointing to it? If not, drag it until you make it point to the navigation controller.

Also, if you're doing that dynamically, have you provided your UIViewController/UITableViewController/UINavigationController Storyboard IDs? Please, double check that by clicking on your view controller in your storyboard, then in the Inspector (right side of Xcode window), go to the third tab and make sure you have set the ID and make sure they are consistent with your code.